# JavaScript Promise Not Awaiting Asynchronous Call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm working with JavaScript promises, but somewhat new to them and having some issues. In the code below "todoService.addTodo(description);" is an asynchronous call to a server. However, the code does not wait for "todoService.addTodo(description);" to finish, and instead continues executing the code, which means "test" is always equal to null. I'm using promises because I thought this would help deal with the asynch calls, do I'm I simply not understanding the concept, or just doing something wrong syntactically?

```
let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
  let test = todoService.addTodo(description);
  console.log(test)

  if (test) {
     console.log("GOOD");
     resolve("OK");
  } else {
      console.log("BAD");
      reject("Unable to connect to server");
  }
});

promise.then(function(result) {
       console.log(result);
    }, function(err) {
        alert(err);
    });
```

Here is the implementation of addTodo():

```
addTodo: function (description) {
        serv.todoUrl ='http://localhost:8080/add?description=' + description;
        serv.todoResource = $resource(serv.todoUrl);
        serv.todoResource.save().$promise.then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            let toReturn = {result: data.result, details: data.details};
            console.log(toReturn);
            return toReturn;
        }, function (error) {
            return null;
        });
```

Comment: Unless todoService.addTodo(description) returns a promise there is no way to stop execution on it. you should be using the promise from within todoService.addTodo(description)

Comment: Is  `toolService.addToDo` marked as `async`? Or is it a promise? In the first case, marking your inner function as async and `await` the todo service is the way to go, in the other, returning todoService.addTodo(description) with a chain of then would be the way to go

Comment: You're not understanding the concept. I'd recommend reading up on it first, see if you can figure out the problem yourself once you get a clearer picture. MDN is usually a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises -- If you're still having trouble afterward, we can go from there.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski I added my implementation of addTodo so you can see it. It itself actually implements a promise.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), and just `return` the promise chain from `addTodo`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `test` is a promise, then `if (test)` is not the right way to deal with it. What's more, you should not create a `new Promise` when `addTodo` already provides the promise.

All you would need is this:

```
todoService.addTodo(description).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}, function(err) {
    alert(err);
});
```

Now that you also added the implementation of `addToDo` in your question, it turns out that it lacks a `return` of the promise you create there, so it just returned `undefined`, which obviously is not a promise. Add `return` here:

```
addTodo: function (description) {
    serv.todoUrl ='http://localhost:8080/add?description=' + description;
    serv.todoResource = $resource(serv.todoUrl);
    return serv.todoResource.save().$promise.then(function (data) {
//  ^^^^^
        console.log(data);
        let toReturn = {result: data.result, details: data.details};
        console.log(toReturn);
        return toReturn;
    }, function (error) {
        return null;
    });
```

Note that the other `return` statements are in the relative callback functions which execute asynchronously, so they don't provide the return value for `addToDo`, but they provide the resolving value for the promise.

NB: Since you treat the rejection case in `addToDo` and don't cascade the error, but just return `null`, `addToDo` will not represent a rejected promise in that case, but a fulfilled one. If you prefer to have the caller of `addToDo` to get a rejected promise in that case, then just remove the rejection handler function from within `addToDo`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. What you are saying makes sense, but I'm still a bit confused. From what I understand, in a promise you have to specify a resolve() and reject(). If "serv.todoResource.save().$promise" is a promise object, then does that mean it's already implemented resolve() and reject()? And if this is the case, shouldn't I just be returning "serv.todoResource.save().$promise" not serv.todoResource.save().$promise.then(function){...};?

Comment: First: yes `save().$promise` returns a promise object, so no need for doing a `resolve` or `reject`: you only need that when you need to synthesise a promise from the ground up. Whether you return `$promise` as is, or add `then` that is up to you. Apparently you wanted something to be done after that `$promise` resolved, and so you added a `then` to do that. But that `then` also returns a promise, so you are still OK with that. This is the power of chaining promises: you keep getting a promise back from a `then`-chain.